# How to configure tomcat 8 to support SCEP. Required for MDM

Tags: authentication, tomcat8, mdm, scep

I have a BlackBerry UEM server and a scep certificate has been assigned to a profile.
I want to achieve single sign on (SSO).

I have a Tomcat 8.5 server, how should i enable Tomcat server to support Client Cert authentication so that it can use the scep when used on the enrolled device.

If anyone has example of a webapp which can be hosted on tomcat to prove the authentication is working, will be helpful.

Waiting in anticipation.

Regards
Sujit J